# Corrigir comando inválido dinamicamente, sem precisar de alias

Tags: bash, shell-script, linha-de-comando, alias

Estou usando **GNU bash versão 4.3.46**.

Um problema que tenho ao digitar os comandos, é que muitas vezes acabo esquecendo um espaço entre o comando e seus parâmetros. Exemplos:

```
cd..
gitlog
```

Quando o correto deveria ser, respectivamente, `cd ..` e `git log`. Os casos mais comuns (comandos que uso com mais frequência) eu resolvi criando vários `alias`, como por exemplo:

```
alias cd..='cd ..'
alias gitlog='git log'
```

Mas como esse meu erro de esquecer o espaço é frequente, eu gostaria de uma solução mais geral, ao invés de ter que criar dezenas de `alias` para cada possibilidade - já que o problema também acontece com comandos que só uso às vezes, e não vale a pena criar um `alias` só pra isso.

---

Primeiro tentei fazer um script que, dado um comando incompleto, mostra as opções para completá-lo. No exemplo abaixo usei `git l` como entrada, só para testar (primeiro eu quis testar um comando com espaço só para ver como funciona; um segundo passo é adaptá-lo para verificar os casos sem espaço):

```
__print_completions() {
    printf '%s\n' "${COMPREPLY[@]}"
}

COMP_WORDS=(git l)
COMP_LINE='git l'
COMP_POINT=6
COMP_CWORD=1
_git
__print_completions
```

A saída foi `log`, o que está correto. Ainda há mais alguns detalhes para trabalhar no script, como por exemplo chamar o comando, caso só haja uma possibilidade, etc. Mas isso não vem ao caso.

O foco da pergunta são os problemas que não estou conseguindo resolver:

- como fazer este script receber como parâmetro o comando que eu digitei?
- como quebrar este comando corretamente?

  - ex: `cd..` pode ser quebrado como `c d..`, `cd ..` e `cd. .`
- como fazer o script ser acionado somente quando o comando que digitei não for encontrado? (ou seja, caso exista um alias ou seja um comando válido, eu não preciso deste script, basta rodar o comando)

**Ou seja**, se eu digito `cd..`, o bash reconhecerá que este comando é inválido e deverá chamar este script (que corrigirá para `cd ..` e rodará o comando corrigido).

Como fazer isso? (caso seja possível)

---

Também estou começando a pensar que talvez este script não seja o melhor caminho, mas não sei se existe outra maneira de resolver isso.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acabei descobrindo que a partir do Bash 4 existe o [*Command not found handler*](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-command-not-found), que é uma função pré-definida que é chamada quando um comando não existe. E o melhor é que você pode sobrescrever esta função (`command_not_found_handle`).

Mas primeiro tive que resolver o problema de um comando poder ser quebrado de maneiras inválidas. Por exemplo, `gitlog` pode ser quebrado de várias maneiras:

```
g itlog
gi tlog
git log <- única opção válida
gitl og
gitlo g
```

Sendo assim, eu optei por ter uma lista de todos os comandos válidos, e a partir daí eu uso estes nomes para evitar uma quebra inválida:

```
find ${PATH//:/ } -type f -perm -u+x 2>/dev/null |awk -F"/" '{print $NF}'|cut -d '.' -f 1|sort|uniq
```

No comando acima, `${PATH//:/ }` são os diretórios do `PATH`, mas substituindo o `:` por espaço, para que o `find` use esta lista de diretórios para fazer a busca.

Eu procuro os arquivos (`-type f`) que eu tenho permissão de executar (`-perm -u+x`). Depois uso `awk` e `cut` para eliminar o caminho completo (como `/usr/bin/comando`) e ficar somente com o nome do arquivo (`comando`).

A seguir, uso `sort` e `uniq` para eliminar nomes repetidos. *Sei que com isso estou ignorando arquivos com nomes iguais em pastas diferentes, mas por enquanto isso não se mostrou um problema.*

Tendo esta lista, eu jogo ela em uma variável e faço um loop pelos resultados. Para cada nome de comando da lista, eu vejo se o que eu digitei começa com o nome do comando, e faço a quebra:

```
# sobrescrever a função para tratar comando não encontrado
command_not_found_handle() {
    CMDS=`find ${PATH//:/ } -type f -perm -u+x 2>/dev/null |awk -F"/" '{print $NF}'|cut -d '.' -f 1|sort|uniq`
    # para cada comando
    for c in $CMDS
    do
        # se o que eu digitei começa com o nome do comando
        if [[ $1 == ${c}* ]]; then
            # roda o comando
            ${c} "${1#${c}}" "${@:2}"
            return $?
        fi
    done
}
```

Por exemplo, se eu digitei `gitlog`, esse é um comando que não existe, e isso é passado para a função, na variável `$1`.

No `for` eu vejo a lista de comandos, e quando `c` for igual a `git`, vai entrar no `if [[ $1 == ${c}* ]]` (o asterisco é o truque para comparar se `$1` começa com `git`).

Dentro do `if`, eu rodo o comando (`${c}`), e quebro a string original (`gitlog`), usando a sintaxe de *string removal*: `${1#${c}}` remove a ocorrência de `${c}` (ou seja, `git`) da variável `$1` (`gitlog`), então o resultado desta expressão é `log`.

Depois eu passo os demais parâmetros do comando, caso existam (`${@:2}`). Assim, se eu digitar `gitlog [parâmetros]`, o comando final será `git log [parâmetros]`.

No final, eu retorno `$?`, que é o [*exit status* do último comando executado](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7248048).

Caso nenhum comando seja encontrado, eu devo retornar o *exit status* padrão para *command not found*, [que é 127](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html). Então eu adicionei outro `return` no final, após o loop, caso este não encontre nenhum comando. Também imprimo uma mensagem, para simular o mesmo comportamento do bash quando um comando não é encontrado.

O código final da função ficou:

```
# sobrescrever a função para tratar comando não encontrado
command_not_found_handle() {
    CMDS=`find ${PATH//:/ } -type f -perm -u+x 2>/dev/null |awk -F"/" '{print $NF}'|cut -d '.' -f 1|sort|uniq`
    # para cada comando
    for c in $CMDS
    do
        # se o que eu digitei começa com o nome do comando
        if [[ $1 == ${c}* ]]; then
            # roda o comando
            ${c} "${1#${c}}" "${@:2}"
            return $?
        fi
    done

    # comando não encontrado, imprimir mensagem e retornar exit status
    printf 'bash: %s: command not found\n' "$1" >&2
    return 127
}
```

Coloquei esta função no meu `.bashrc` e está funcionando bem.

Às vezes demora um ou 2 segundos, talvez porque fazer um `find` no `PATH` não é a coisa mais rápida do mundo (talvez eu não devesse fazer essa busca toda hora).

O caso de `cd..` não funciona por causa [deste pequeno detalhe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/255415). Então este é o único que deixei como `alias` mesmo. Mas os outros comandos funcionam normalmente.

---

**PS:** Os comandos de substituição (`${1#${c}}` e `${PATH//:/ }`) eu peguei [neste link](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html).

Comment: Muito interessante!

Answer (score 4):

Não sei se é possível fazer exatamente o que você quer, mas você pode usar o comando `trap` para capturar o sinal de `DEBUG` disparado por cada comando que você executa, vejamos:

Configurando a `trap`:

```
$ trap 'echo -e "Capturei o comando: $BASH_COMAND"' DEBUG
```

Removendo a `trap`:

```
$ trap - DEBUG
```

Exemplo:

```
$ trap 'echo -e "Capturei o comando: $BASH_COMMAND"' DEBUG
Capturei o comando: __vte_prompt_command

$ c d . . 
Capturei o comando: c d . .
bash: c: command not found...
Capturei o comando: __vte_prompt_command

$ trap - DEBUG
Capturei o comando: trap - DEBUG
```

Você pode criar um *script* auxiliar que será executado recebendo a variável com o comando executado (`$BASH_COMMAND`) como argumento, por exemplo:

```
$ trap './foobar.sh $BASH_COMAND' DEBUG
```

A implementação de `foobar.sh` seria algo como:

```
#!/bin/bash

case "$1" in

    'cd..')
    ;;

    'c d . .')
    ;;

    'c d..')
    ;;

esac
```

Referência: https://superuser.com/questions/175799/does-bash-have-a-hook-that-is-run-before-executing-a-command

Comment: No fim acabei encontrando outra solução (veja [a minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/300974/112052)). De qualquer forma, obrigado pela sua resposta, pois aprendi um comando novo (`trap`).